# Annotating seaborn regplot parameters to the plot

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to make scatter plots with `r2`, `p` and `rmse` values using `seaborn.regplot`. But following code returns an error of `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'map_dataframe'`

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 5), sharey=True)


g = sns.regplot(x='est_fmc', y='1h_surface', data=new_df, ax=axes[0])
def annotate(data, **kws):
    slope, intercept, rvalue, pvalue, stderr = scipy.stats.linregress(x = data['est_fmc'], y= data['1h_surface'] )
    rmse = mean_squared_error(data['est_fmc'], data['1h_surface'], squared=False)
    print(slope, intercept, rvalue, pvalue, rmse)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(.02, .9, 'r2={:.2f}, p={:.2g}, rmse = {:.2f}'.format(rvalue**2, pvalue, rmse),
            transform=ax.transAxes)
g.map_dataframe(annotate)


g = sns.regplot(x='est_fmc', y='1h_profile', data=new_df, ax = axes[1] )
def annotate(data, **kws):
    slope, intercept, rvalue, pvalue, stderr = scipy.stats.linregress(x = data['est_fmc'], y= data['1h_profile'] )
    rmse = mean_squared_error(data['est_fmc'], data['1h_profile'], squared=False)
    print(slope, intercept, rvalue, pvalue, rmse)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(.02, .9, 'r2={:.2f}, p={:.2g}, rmse = {:.2f}'.format(rvalue**2, pvalue, rmse),
            transform=ax.transAxes)
g.map_dataframe(annotate)
```

Is there a way to work around? I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An important aspect of seaborn is the [difference between figure-level and axes-level functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions).  [`sns.regplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) is an axes-level function. It gets an `ax` (indicating the subplot) as an optional parameter, and always returns the `ax` on which the plot has been created.

[`map_dataframe`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.map_dataframe.html) is meant to work with figure-level functions (which create a grid of subplots). It can work together with a function such as `relplot`. Note that figure-level functions don't accept an `ax` as parameter, they always create their own new figure.

In your case, you can modify the `annotate` function with an `ax` parameter, and also a parameter for `x` and `y` to make it work for both subplots. (An important concept in Python is ["DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).)

Here is the modified code, starting from some test data. (A further improvement would be to also put the call to `regplot` into the `annotate` function, renaming that function to something like "regplot_with_annotation").

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

def annotate(ax, data, x, y):
    slope, intercept, rvalue, pvalue, stderr = scipy.stats.linregress(x=data[x], y=data[y])
    rmse = mean_squared_error(data[x], data[y], squared=False)
    ax.text(.02, .9, f'r2={rvalue ** 2:.2f}, p={pvalue:.2g}, rmse={rmse:.2f}', transform=ax.transAxes)

est_fmc = np.random.uniform(0, 10, 100)
oneh_surface = 2 * est_fmc + np.random.normal(0, 5, 100) + 10
oneh_profile = 3 * est_fmc + np.random.normal(0, 3, 100) + 5

new_df = pd.DataFrame({'est_fmc': est_fmc, '1h_surface': oneh_surface, '1h_profile': oneh_profile})

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 5), sharey=True)

ax = sns.regplot(x='est_fmc', y='1h_surface', data=new_df, ax=axes[0])
annotate(ax, data=new_df, x='est_fmc', y='1h_surface')

ax = sns.regplot(x='est_fmc', y='1h_profile', data=new_df, ax=axes[1])
annotate(ax, data=new_df, x='est_fmc', y='1h_profile')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.regplot with annotation]